# smooth Nuxt/Vue transition on the rest of the page when displaying and hidding a list of elements

Tags: javascript, vue.js, css-transitions, nuxt.js, vuejs-transition-group

I got a list of grid items , and a button switching between "see more" and "see less". On click on the "see more" button, all the list is displayed.  on click on the see less, only 3 items are displayed. we got a nice transition when displaying all the items, but when we hide them, all the elements on the bottom don't follow the motion. How can I make the transition smooth and don't leave the user at the middle of the paragraphe ?

template exemple :

```
<div>
  <transition-group name="list" class="grid">
      <div v-for="(content,index) in contents" :key="index" class="card">
        <h4>
          {{index}}
        </h4>
      </div>
  </transition-group>

  <button @click="onClickSeeButton">
    {{ seeButton }}
  </button>

  <p>
      Some text...
  </p>
</div>
```

I used those css properties for the transition

```
.list-enter-active, .list-leave-active {
  transition: all 1s;
}
.list-enter, .list-leave-to {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

the Script goes as follow :

```
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    els: [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12], // from 0 to infinite
    seeMore: true
  },
  computed: {
    contents: function(){
        return this.seeMore ? this.els.filter((el,index) => index < 3 ) : this.els
    },
    readButton: function(){
        return this.seeMore ? 'see more' : 'see less'
    }
  },
  methods: {
    onClickReadButton: function(){
        this.seeMore = !this.seeMore
    }
  }
})
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ghivalla/v5me216c/3/

Comment: is this still not working for you I just went to the jsfiddle and it seems to collapse out of sight and bring the paragraph text back up.

Comment: yea but in fact I want a smooth transition, the cards disapear in 1s with the opacity 0, and just after that the text jump roughly to the top,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
.list-enter-active, .list-leave-active {
  transition: all 1s;
  opacity: 1;
}
.list-enter, .list-leave-to {
  opacity: 0; height: 0;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/w4v9g6us/

Also here is a good place to read more about vue and transitions https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/transitions.html

Comment: Thanks for you help !